# What is with the sudden increase in naa answers?

Tags: discussion

Such as here: [How to move Applications from phone to SD Card?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/30448/how-to-move-applications-from-phone-to-sd-card/34264#34264)

There seems to have been a sudden increase, or is this normal?

Comment: Wow, 11 flags this morning all of them were very, very poor answers or non-answers. Keep flagging them and we'll take care of them.

Comment: NAA as in "non-answer answers", right?

Comment: @ce4 correct, didn't want to put that in the title as it would be too long.

Comment: I'm basically agreed with Al.  If you see repeated non-answers from the same user please mention that in a custom flag, but most of them seem to be one-offs from new users who must have followed a link or something.

Comment: Also worth remembering that as these are new visitors to the site, who don't necessarily know how we work, that it is worth leaving a comment explaining what they've done wrong and what they should do next time. Otherwwise just closing their answer can seem very unfriendly

Answer (score 10, accepted):

More Google Juice?

Site mentioned in a popular discussion forum as a place to get good answers?

A lot of people new to Android? (Considering the apparent great popularity of the Nexus 4/7/10 and the latest Samsung Galaxy, this actually seems most likely.)

I don't know that we can ever know. It seems to happen occasionally. Just downvote and/or flag and/or vote to close and/or vote to delete as appropriate and move on.